# How to get a value from scrollpane?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

How can I get a value from table with ScrollPane and set it to the field? My code isn't working.

```
table_3 = new JTable();
table_3.setBounds(12, 27, 315, 220);

    JScrollPane scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel) table_3.getModel();
            int selectedRowIndex=table_3.getSelectedRow();
            txtArtist.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
            textField_4.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());

        }
    });
    scrollPane3.setBounds(12, 27,315,220);
    panel_4.add(scrollPane3);
    scrollPane3.setViewportView(table_3);
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? If yes can you post it as well?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) *"My code isn't working."* Your comment isn't helpful in determining the solution. Pls expand.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a value from table with ScrollPane

```
 scrollPane3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

Add the MouseListener to the component you actually click on.

In this case you want to handle the mouse click on the table.